# Wordpress or own cms?

Tags: php, wordpress

I asked a question before about using a content management system (sort of) and the response I got was to use wordpress. I'm having second thoughts though, as I only want the contents of one div throughout my whole website to change daily. I also don't need the comments or other such features of wordpress. Can I do anything with php and a database to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: This isn't really a programming question.

Comment: You can do that without a database. Use a directory to put the <div> html files into. Set `srand(time()%90000)` and read in the filenames, pick one with `rand($numfiles)` (or just pick the newest file) and output it with `readfile()` at the right position. -- Btw, your question was closed because it ends in "Can I do" instead of "How can I" and concrete coding issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Points to consider:

- Wordpress allows you to create "pages" in addition to blogposts. It's probably what you intend to do.
- You only see the need to change one  now, but what about next year?
- If you're using a webhosting service, it's likely you already have access to PHP and mysql databases through them. It'll be worth it to experiment with creating your own tables and scripts with PHP *and* setting up a Wordpress.
- You could even just use PHP to access files on your website now, and rotate through those, avoiding a CMS altogether!

And so on...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I didn't say this in the description but this website is for a school project. So I unfortunately won't be maintaining it "next year". Could you give a little guidance to the php scripting you talked about? I'm not asking you to write the whole thing but possibly a link to something that helped you. Thanks